# To JNDI or not to JNDI when embedding an application server?

Tags: java, jetty, jndi

I'm coming from a full application server background and considering running apps on a lightweight embedded server such as Jetty.

I've always used JNDI to look up connection pools for things like database connections but I'm wondering whether that's the best approach for the lightweight case. It seems that if I use JNDI I don't get anything beneficial, but I do get variation in how different containers are configured and additional complexity in setting up.

The alternative I can see is just embedding a connection pool implementation in my app. As I use Spring, this approach has a little less configuration required, what configuration is needed is all in one place (with the ability to look up simple name-value properties such as connection details from elsewhere if needed) and would seem to work regardless of the context (dev/test/live) and what container I deploy with.

Am I missing something here? Should I still use JNDI if I am embedding an application server in my application? If so, why?

Comment: Consider looking into Dependency Injection for future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on your situation.

JNDI (to me) is a mechanism to achieving a decoupling between what your deploying and where you are deploying it.  Such that when you are deploying you are assuming certain resources will be available and they are going to be labeled X, Y and Z.  JNDI is the simple (kinda) mechanism to provide those resources in a basically uniform way.  If your going to have potentially multiple different supported databases and you want to write all your code against some data source...your going to need that datasource configured *somewhere* and jndi gives some place to do it. If your using some sort of tooling that makes setting up jndi a cakewalk, then great, use it.

In an embedded situation the circumstances really don't change, things still need to be setup somewhere.  However, in the course of your embedded application you find yourself writing both sides of the jndi equation, then do ask yourself if you need this extra layer of abstraction.

If your just using jndi because that is whatever everyone else does, but you only use postgres really and you just need that database driver...then what is the point of the extra layer of complexity for your application.  If you really like spring and spring gives you an easier way of configuring the bits and pieces you needs and injects it where you need it...don't use jndi.

fwiw, it kinda sounds like you don't need jndi anymore :)

Comment: Good way of putting it "writing both sides of the JNDI equation".

Comment: Even though the _application_ is embedded and complete, it does not mean that all libraries used know that.  You still need to wire these together.